# Добавил сортировку BindingList(), почему не работает?

Tags: c#, сортировка, datagrid

Я новичок в этом, мог ошибиться с кодом для сортировки BindingList(), буду безумно благодарен если  рабочий код. Код показывает таблицу в DataGrid, но по нажатию на заголовки не сортирует по имени. Ошибок нигде никаких не выдает, все в норме. Код запускается, но не сортирует.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DOCTORSGUIDE
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a generic collection that supports data binding and additionally supports sorting.
    /// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993236.aspx
    /// If the elements are IComparable it uses that; otherwise compares the ToString()
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements in the list.</typeparam>
    [Serializable]
    public class SortableBindingList<Model> : BindingList<Model>
    {
        private bool _isSorted;
        private ListSortDirection _sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        private PropertyDescriptor _sortProperty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the list supports sorting.
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the list is sorted.
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool IsSortedCore
        {
            get { return _isSorted; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the direction the list is sorted.
        /// </summary>
        protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
        {
            get { return _sortDirection; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the property descriptor that is used for sorting the list if sorting is implemented in a derived class; otherwise, returns null
        /// </summary>
        protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
        {
            get { return _sortProperty; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes any sort applied with ApplySortCore if sorting is implemented
        /// </summary>
        protected override void RemoveSortCore()
        {
            _sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            _sortProperty = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sorts the items if overridden in a derived class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="prop"></param>
        /// <param name="direction"></param>
        protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            _sortProperty = prop;
            _sortDirection = direction;

            if (_sortProperty == null) return; //nothing to sort on
            List<Model> list = Items as List<Model>;
            if (list == null) return;

            list.Sort(delegate (Model lhs, Model rhs)
            {

                object lhsValue = lhs == null ? null : _sortProperty.GetValue(lhs);
                object rhsValue = rhs == null ? null : _sortProperty.GetValue(rhs);
                int result = 0;
                if (lhsValue == null && rhsValue == null)
                {
                    result = 0;
                }
                else if (lhsValue == null)
                {
                    result = -1;
                }
                else if (rhsValue == null)
                {
                    result = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (lhsValue is IComparable)
                    {
                        result = ((IComparable)lhsValue).CompareTo(rhsValue);
                    }
                    else if (!lhsValue.Equals(rhsValue))//not comparable, compare ToString
                    {
                        result = lhsValue.ToString().CompareTo(rhsValue.ToString());
                    }
                }
                if (_sortDirection == ListSortDirection.Descending)
                    result = -result;
                return result;
            });

            _isSorted = true;
            //fire an event that the list has been changed.
            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
        }

        public static implicit operator List<Model>(SortableBindingList<Model> sortableBindingList)
        {
            return sortableBindingList.Items.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

```
 private readonly string Path = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\Dannie.json";
        private BindingList<Model> Dannie;
        private SaveFile saveFile;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            saveFile = new SaveFile(Path);

            try
            {
                Dannie = saveFile.Load();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //если ошибка, приложение закрывается
                Close();
            }


            DataGridView1.ItemsSource = Dannie;
            Dannie.ListChanged += Dannie_ListChanged;
        }

        private void Dannie_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded || e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted || e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged) 
            { 
                try
                {
                    saveFile.Save(sender);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //если ошибка, приложение закрывается
                    Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridView1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="0,34,8,119" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Grid.Column="1" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Namee}" Header="Name" Width="145" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Symptoms}" Header="Symptoms" Width="145" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Procedures}" Header="Procedures" Width="145"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Recommended}" Header="Recommended medicines" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Ерунду делаете. 1. Научитесь делать привязки, нормальные, где будет задан один `DataContext`, а дальше, в XAML будет указываться источник, а не так, что сейчас вы дергаете контролы из C# кода. 2. Зачем вам делать свою коллекцию, если фильтрацию и сортировку в WPF отлично делает `ICollectionView`? 3.  Научитесь самостоятельно писать XAML, позиционировать объекты, а не использовать конструктор, ибо `Margin="0,34,8,119"`...